# Is every $n$-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ a Lagrangian submanifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, symplectic-geometry, grassmannian

Let $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ have the standard symplectic form $\omega = dx_1\wedge dy_1 + \cdots + dx_n\wedge dx_n$. If we consider an $n$-dimensional subvector space of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ as a submanifold, is this submanifold Lagrangian? My main motivation for this question is to see if $Gr_\mathbb{R}(2n,n)$ is a parameter space for Lagrangian submanifolds.

Comment: The question is poorly formed (and the title is incorrect, since not all subspaces are dimension $n$). The answer is no. Take the subspace of points $\{(x_1,y_1,0,0)\}$. This is symplectic, not lagrangian.

Comment: I recommend chapter 1 of these notes to learn more about symplectic linear algebra http://www.math.toronto.edu/mein/teaching/LectureNotes/sympl.pdf This should also contain the answer to your motivating question.